# How to prevent a document from getting updated in mongodb if it already exists?

Tags: angular, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to coding and I am developing an application using SpringBoot using SpringData MongoDB, Angular and MongoDB in which the user is filling and submitting a form. But I want that if the user and his details already exist in the database (MongoDB), the values shouldn't get updated.

Comment: Please post what you've tried doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your code here. Please provide it next time you ask a question so more people can answer your question. I am also assuming you are using a MEAN-stack (node.js in your backend).

This may be your issue:

By default mongoDB has upsert behavior in the `save()` method. This means that a record will be updated if it already exists in the database. The [save() method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#save) will be deprecated. So don't use it.

```
Collection.save( { _id : 100, item : "juice" } )
```

You should use `insertOne()` instead. You can [read the official insertOne() documentation here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#insertOne).

```
Collection.insertOne( { _id : 100, item : "juice" } )
```